# CSS absolute positioning is not moving to parent, the parent is relative

Tags: css, position

I am trying to absolutely position sideways text inside a div that there are multiple occurences of.

Each child has position: absolute; ,
and each parent has position: relative;

```
    .parent{
    width: 24%;
    display: inline-block;
    float: left;
    border-left: 1px solid #FFA500;
    position: relative;
    }

    .child{
    display: inline-block;
    line-height: 1.5;
    height: 5%;
    position: absolute;
    top: 0px;
    right: 0px;
    transform: translate(0px, 100%) rotate(90deg);
    overflow: hidden;
    float: right;
}
```

Of of the children go to the same exact place on the page, which seems to be the first childs parent.
The structure is

```
Parent
    child
close
close
```

for all 4 divs.

Can anyone please help?

Comment: Please post a complete code example.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your css, if your parent has no content other than the absolute position child div, then the parent has a 0 height declaration - so you have to set the height of the parent div in pixels in order to give it a place in the DOM.

Answer (score 0):

Your height: 5% on the .child may be what is throwing it off (it was for me).  That, or there could be other css that is overriding something for you.  Fiddle here: https://jsfiddle.net/tagb3yja/

```
.parent{
  width: 24%;
  display: inline-block;
  float: left;
  border-left: 1px solid #FFA500;
  position: relative;
  background: yellow;
}

.child{
  position: absolute;
  display: inline-block;
  line-height: 1.5;
  top: 0px;
  right: 0px;
  transform: translate(0px, 100%) rotate(90deg);
  overflow: hidden;
  float: right;
  background: silver;
}
```